# How to enable development mode on visionOS?

Tags: xcode, visionos, vision-pro

I want to build my visionOS app to my Vision Pro for the first time. There is no cable or any way to physically connect the device to my MacBook, so how do I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Vision Pro:

- Go to Settings > General > Remote Devices and select your computer

On your Mac:

- Go to Xcode > Window > Devices and Simulators
- Find your Vision Pro in the Devices list on the left
- Pair your Vision Pro using the code seen in the Settings app in Vision Pro

Answer (score 5):

You must have an Apple Silicon Mac, then follow the steps below.

Connect to same wifi network

1. On Vision Pro

   - Settings > General > Remote Devices
2. On Mac

   - Xcode -> Devices & Simulators -> Select the Vision Pro &
     enter the code
   - Run a build targeted at your vision pro device which should
     now be a run destination

(Developer mode setting wasn't visible till I did this), you will get an error saying developer mode is not enabled.

3. On Vision Pro

   - Privacy & Security > Developer Mode

Comment: After you enable Developer Mode on the VP, there's a reboot of the VP and a couple of confirmation dialogs, too. Also: if you've updated the VP to visionOS 1.0.2 with the update of about Feb 6 2024, you won't be able to pair to Xcode 15.2. You'll need 15.3 beta (beta 2 worked fine for me).

Answer (score 2):

There’s a $300 strap to connect your Vision Pro to your Mac, providing a hardwired USB-C connection (debugging, testing) that’s locked to only be purchasable through your developer account. (bottom of page https://developer.apple.com/visionos/resources/). Mailorder only, no in-store pickup.

via @heckj

Comment: For now, it's only available to developers with a US-based Apple Developer account, enrolled in the Apple Developer program. (Source: John Gruber, Daring Fireball - [https://daringfireball.net/linked/2024/02/02/vision-pro-developer-strap)