# How do I connect my Vision Pro to Xcode for development on my Mac?

Tags: xcode, macos, visionos, vision-pro

How do I connect my Vision Pro to Xcode for development on my Mac?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable develop mode on visionOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77930780/how-to-enable-develop-mode-on-visionos)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First, make sure your computer and your Vision Pro are on the same wireless network.

- On your Vision Pro, go to Settings -> General -> Remote Devices.

  - If there is an already existing computer, you will need to clear it
  - Keep this open on the Vision Pro
- Switch over to your your Mac, go to Xcode. Window -> Devices and Simulators.

  - You should see the Vision Pro in the disconnected list on the left
    column.
  - Select it and click the pair button
  - Enter in the code on your Mac you see in your Vision Pro
- Back on your Vision Pro go to Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Developer Mode

You'll get some warnings about security being lessened and need to restart the Vision Pro.