# How to test visionOS apps on actual hardware?

Tags: visionos

Is it possible to test the app I'm developing on my Vision Pro or can I only test in the simulator?

EDIT: Turns out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77934170/how-do-i-connect-my-vision-pro-to-xcode-for-development-on-my-mac) is really what I was looking for.

Comment: Do you have physical access to a Vision Pro? Then of course you can load your app onto it for testing. What specifically are you stuck with there? If you don’t have a Vision Pro at hand… I’m not sure what kind of answer you’re hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

If your visionOS app doesn't use such technologies as Hand Tracking, Image Tracking, Scene Reconstruction, Capturing Persona and Video, Gaze Tracking, or in other words, everything that requires the physical presence of Vision Pro device (which has IMU, RGB Cameras, LiDAR, TrueDepth sensors, etc), then you can easily test the performance of your app on visionOS Simulator. Why not?

Otherwise, you need to test your app only on an actual Vision Pro device.