# Cannot pair Apple Vision Pro with Xcode

Tags: xcode, vision-pro

I am following [the official documentation on how to connect the device](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Xcode/running-your-app-in-simulator-or-on-a-device) but the Apple Vision Pro doesn't show up in the devices list to begin the process.

1. Device and Mac are on the same Wi-Fi network
2. Network is confirmed compatible with Bonjour (Airdrop works fine, can connect the display to my mac, I even tried in the Apple Store on their wifi network with no luck)
3. Settings > General > Remote Devices is selected and "Ready to Pair" is showing
4. Device is not showing up in the list in the Devices and Simulators window in Xcode

Comment: Did you enable developer mode?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enable development mode on visionOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77930780/how-to-enable-development-mode-on-visionos)

Answer (score 0):

You need an Apple Silicon Mac (M1, M2, M3 chip) to deploy on an Apple Vision Pro device. It doesn't connect with an Intel Mac in Xcode 15 for development.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionos

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).